# Height of ContentPage gets set to 504?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I've had my share of "what the f%$@" Xamarin forms errors. But this one tops the cake. I've spent about 3 hours now trying to figure out why this page only gets set to 504 height, and nothing I do seems to fix it. Literally have a empty page like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XamarinMobile.Controls;assembly=XamarinMobile"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinMobile.Classes;assembly=XamarinMobile"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:XamarinMobile.Converters;assembly=XamarinMobile"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinMobile.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinMobile"
             xmlns:customRenderers="clr-namespace:XamarinMobile.CustomRenderers;assembly=XamarinMobile"
             x:Class="XamarinMobile.CommentsPage">

      <Label Text="Test"></Label>

    </ContentPage>
```

And I get this result:

[image]

Literally it's identical to other pages that don't have this problem. Any insights? Any way to force it to be a minimum height of screen height? So annoying.

Comment: Did you check the designer.cs file?

Comment: Did I check it for what?

Comment: Anything that may be specifically setting a value in the generated code-behind.  Basically search for `.Height =`

Comment: No, not setting height to 504. If I was, then this wouldn't be an issue :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue seemed to be that I wasn't calling a method I needed to call.

`NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar`

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar/p/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/System.Boolean/

The behavior of this is odd. It 'allocates' space for a navigation bar if you don't specify it at all. You'd think it'd default to false, but seems like it defaults to true. Setting it false fixed the issue:

`Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`

Answer (score 0):

You could manually set the height of a layout to match the screen.

```
App.ScreenWidth = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
App.ScreenHeight = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

Then set a relative or stacklayout to height / width to the results. I think you would be better off taking a look at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/ and using perhaps a stacklout layout with vertical option set to fill. I would expect that to match screen height.

Comment: No, `App.ScreenHeight` is set correctly. In fact, I already do this code that you have. I set the `HeightRequest` and `MinimumHeightRequest` to `App.ScreenHeight` (which is 568 when I debug) and then somehow it sets it to 504.